# HttpContext.Current.Session is null em thread

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, thread, multithreading

Olá, Estou com um problema no meu código. Estou Fazendo uma função que dura cerca de 3/4 horas de duração, e então decidi fazer essa função em uma thread para que a mesma não bloqueie o funcionamento geral do sistema. após algumas pesquisas encontrei algumas soluções e testei.
Porem durante essa função eu faço acesso ao banco e quando faço isso a minha thread estoura erro:

> HttpContext.Current.Session is null

então procurei aind amais meios de passar o context e a session e cheguei a esses 2 resultado:

```
var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ExecuteLongOperation), ctx);
```

e:

```
     HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        HttpContext.Current = ctx;
        ExecuteLongOperation();
    }));
    t.Start();
```

até esse ponto o HttpContext.Current.Session tem a session com valor, com  tudo certo.

e no meu metodo:

```
  private void ExecuteLongOperation(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpContext.Current = (HttpContext)state;  .....}
```

e quando dou um quickwatch no HttpContext.Current.Session, a mesma continua nula.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Ja tentei tambem passar a session mas ela é read-only.

Alguma sugestão?
Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A session faz parte do contexto da requisição. Quando a requisição termina, a session deixa de existir. Em outras palavras, você está tentando acessar um objeto que é dependente da requisição (session) em um método que não é.

Se você precisa de valores da session, passe esses valores para o seu método. Passar uma referência pra session também não vai funcionar pelo motivo dito acima.

Se você estiver usando .net >= 4.5.2, pode usar o [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx) pra isso.

Exemplo de uso [aqui](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/).

Comment: o seu comentário me ajudou bastante, eu precisava manda uma referencia da minha aplicação, para poder criar dados pôs o ORM depende da sessão da minha aplicação, então eu passei para a thread a application e la dentro criei uma sessão para garantir atomicidade da aplicação.Enfim Obrigado pela ajuda